# ConcurrentHashMap and operations that span 2 separate calls

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I understand that ConcurrentHashMap methods are thread safe but what about compound operations that are not atomic for example see this piece of code - if 2 different threads call it at the same time with the same “myKey” isn’t it possible for a race condition to occur?

myMap is a ConcurrentHashMap

```
myValues = myMap.get(myKey);
if (myValues == null) {
    myValues = new List()
    myMap.add(myKey, myValues);
}
myValue.add(new list item);
```

How do I write the above in a thread safe way with just ConcurrentHashMap & without using separate Locks etc,

putIfAbsent does not seem to solve the issue either or is something like this feasible:

```
myValues =  myMap.putIfAbsent(myKey, new List());
myValues.add(new list item);
```

Is this correct and thread safe?
Thanks

Comment: Regardless of how you handle the `ConcurrentHashMap`, you're trying to append to the same list from multiple threads at the same time. That's not going to be safe just because the list happens to be a value in a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) which is atomic:

Documentation:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
>   to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
>   into this map unless null. The entire method invocation is performed
>   atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key. Some
>   attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be
>   blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be
>   short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of
>   this map.

Simple usage:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
List<String> list = map.computeIfAbsent("myKey", key -> new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>());
```

**Edit**
As @Holger properly noticed `ArrayList` is not safe to use in this case. Much safer is using [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) which is a thread-safe variant of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Holger, What do you mean by "broken"?

Comment: `ArrayList` is not thread safe. So it must not be used by multiple threads concurrently. But the whole point of using `computeIfAbsent("myKey", key -> new ArrayList<>())` on a `ConcurrentHashMap`, is the intention of using it by multiple threads, without an additional synchronization. The OP’s example already includes invoking `add` on it.

Comment: @Holger, of course you are right. I just wanted to show how new list can be created and used `ArrayList` just for example. But this inattentive example introduced problem with list itself. Thank you for your comment!